# Child extends Parent, does Child.doSomething(HashMap<Integer,Integer> map) override Parent.doSomething(Map<Integer,Integer> map)?

Tags: java, overriding

Does Child.doSomething(HashMap<Integer,Integer> map) override Parent.doSomething(Map<Integer,Integer> map) ?

```
public class Parent {
    public void doSomething(Map<String,String> map){
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void doSomething(HashMap<String,String> map){
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.
They have different parameters—*Map* versus *HashMap*.

It would need to be,

```java
public void doSomething(Map<String, String> map)
```

*[Java Language Specification – 8.4.9. Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9)*.

> *"... If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.*
>
> *This fact causes no difficulty and never of itself results in a compile-time error. There is no required relationship between the return types or between the throws clauses of two methods with the same name, unless their signatures are override-equivalent. ..."*

And, in terms of *"override-equivalent"*,

*[Java Language Specification – 8.4.2. Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)*.

> *"... Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.*
>
> *The signature of a method m<sub>1</sub> is a subsignature of the signature of a method m<sub>2</sub> if either:*
>
> - *m<sub>2</sub> has the same signature as m<sub>1</sub>, or*
> - *the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>.*
>
> *Two method signatures m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> are override-equivalent iff either m<sub>1</sub> is a subsignature of m<sub>2</sub> or m<sub>2</sub> is a subsignature of m<sub>1</sub>. ..."*

And, finally, in terms of *"formal parameter types"*,

*[Java Language Specification – 8.4.1. Formal Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)*, and *[8.3. Field Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)*.

> *FormalParameter:*
>   *{VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId*
>   *VariableArityParameter*
> ...
> *UnannType:*
>   *UnannPrimitiveType*
>   *UnannReferenceType*
> ...
> *UnannReferenceType:*
>   *UnannClassOrInterfaceType*
>   *UnannTypeVariable*
>   *UnannArrayType*
> ...
> *UnannClassOrInterfaceType:*
>   *UnannClassType*
>   *UnannInterfaceType*

So, they must have the same formal parameter types, to be deemed as, having been *overridden*; which in this situation, defines them as simply *overloaded*.

A class and interface are not interchangeable, via *UnannClassType*, and *UnannInterfaceType*.